# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1 [JAVASCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, json

Amigos, necesito su ayuda. Tengo problemas del lado de JavaScript para convertir un string a JSON, el mensaje de error dice: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
y en pantalla muestro el string que recibo. Gracias por su tiempo :)
[image: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que el formato JSON lleva comillas dobles

> " estas "

y el string está con comillas simples

> ' estas otras '

de modo que `JSON.parse` no podrá convertir el string en un objeto. parece que ese json lo estás construyendo en un string concatenando con variables.

Si ese es el caso la **solución real** es poner comillas dobles en lugar de comillas simples

> {"nombre":"DSADA","apellido":"OIUOIU"}

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
let string = '{"nombre":"Antonio","telefono":"5544632354"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(string))
console.log("mi nombre es", JSON.parse(string).nombre)
```

Answer (score 0):

ESTA ES LA RESPUESTA:

> var obj = data.replace(/'/g,"\""); //Permite reemplazar ' por "
>
> ```
> obj = JSON.parse(obj);
> ```

Comment: Es una mala práctica pues lo que se intenta hacer en la pregunta es convertir un json a objeto siendo que la cadena no es un JSON, lo que propones funcionará pero no lo más óptimo

Comment: Tuve que resolverlo de ese modo, ya que era la respuesta que devolvía ese servicio, al igual que el ejemplo de arriba lo único que hice fue modificar la cadena para que pudiera ser manipulable por JSON.parse. Saludos